# How to change border color of textarea on :focus

Tags: html, css

I want to change border color of TEXTAREA on focus. But my code doesn't seem to working properly.

The code is on [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ffS4S/).

```html
<form name = "myform" method = "post" action="insert.php"  onsubmit="return validateform()" style="width:40%">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name." name="name" maxlength="300" class="input">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter E-mail." name="address" maxlength="300" class="input">
    <textarea placeholder="Enter Message." name="descrip" class="input" ></textarea>    
    <br>
    <input class="button secondary" type=submit name="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Here is the CSS

```css
.input {
    border:0; 
    padding:10px; 
    font-size:1.3em; 
    font-family:"Ubuntu Light","Ubuntu","Ubuntu Mono","Segoe Print","Segoe UI";
    color:#ccc; 
    border:solid 1px #ccc; 
    margin:0 0 20px; 
    width:300px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
    box-shadow: inner 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 3px; 
    border-radius: 3px;    
  }

input:focus { 
    outline: none !important;
    border-color: #719ECE;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
 }
```

Comment: the color you chose for the border looks like the default color....

Answer (score 468, accepted):

```css
.input:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
  }
```

Comment: You could also change the input:focus to .input:focus as you are already using that class on the textarea. You get rid of the extra selector that way.

Comment: Just curious, buy why do textareas need `outline: none` but normal textbox inputs do not?

Comment: I think better is using outline and shadow together "outline: solid 2px #8dc63f; box-shadow: 0 0 21px #8dc63f;" :-)

Comment: worked for me without use of !important as well.

Comment: Don't use `outline: none`, use `outline: transparent` as it's more friendly to people with assistive technologies if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 61):

**There is an input:focus as there is a textarea:focus**

```css
    input:focus { 
        outline: none !important;
        border-color: #719ECE;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
    }
    textarea:focus { 
        outline: none !important;
        border-color: #719ECE;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
    }
```

Comment: Both of the rules can be combined as follows - `input:focus, textarea:focus { 
    outline: none !important;
    border-color: #719ECE;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
}` If you want same effect on both type of elements.

Comment: Its clean but how its this still good for Accessibility?

Comment: for me `textarea:focus{
 background-color: lightyellow;
}` is not working

Answer (score 28):

Probably a more appropriate way of *changing* outline color is using the [`outline-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-color) CSS rule.

```css
textarea {
  outline-color: #719ECE;
}
```

or for input

```css
input {
  outline-color: #719ECE;
}
```

`box-shadow` isn't quite the same thing and it may look different than the outline, especially if you apply custom styling to your element.

Comment: Yes, but isn't the outline a rectangle? Not good if you are styling the buttons/input with border-radius.

Comment: The outline is what browsers use for highlighting focused fields for accessibility. I would recommend sticking to it whenever possible. Obviously, you're free to create workarounds if your design is very specific :)

Comment: For anyone wondering, outline-color works fine with border-radius.

Answer (score 9):

so simple :

```
 outline-color : green!important;
```

the whole CSS for my react-boostrap button is:

```css
 .custom-btn {
     font-size:1.9em;
     background: #2f5bff;
     border: 2px solid #78e4ff;
     border-radius: 3px;
     padding: 50px 70px;
     outline-color : blue !important;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     user-select: auto;
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

This will work fine.

```
input:focus{
    outline: none;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

On my personal code I removed the **border** property because it changed component size.

```
.input:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.125rem red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try out this probably it will work

```
input{
outline-color: #fff //your color
outline-style: none // it depend on you 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need just in scss varible

```
$input-btn-focus-width:       .05rem !default;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS's `pseudo-class` to do that. A pseudo-class is used to define a special state of an element.

there is a `::focus` pseudo-class that is used to select the element that has focus.
So you can hook it in your CSS like this

**Using class**

```css
.my-input::focus {
  outline-color: green;
}
```

**Using Id**

```css
#my-input::focus {
  outline-color: red;
}
```

**Directly selecting element**

```css
input::focus {
  outline-color: blue;
}
```

**Using attribute selector**

```css
input[type="text"]::focus {
  outline-color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this way is working in the major browsers:

```
.input:focus {
   outline: 2px solid red;
   outline-offset: 1.5px; // the offset
 }
```