# How to change the border color of the dropdown box of select?

Tags: css

[image]

Is there any way to change that blue border line of the dropdown box to something else?

Answer (score 3):

```
@Joshua,

Did you try this

.input:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
}
```

[Find it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156594/how-to-change-border-color-of-textarea-on-focus)

Comment: That only applies to the select itself, not the dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14639698/4171578) it cannot be changed with CSS, as it is rendered by the operating system:

[image]

(source of the picture is the linked answer on SO)

You can only change the border and the outline of the select box itself.