# Can't change border color when input field is active

Tags: html, css, sass

I can't change border color when the input field is active. I tried using input:active, input:focus. What I want is the color of input's border to change when user clicks on it.

The CSS code :

```
input {
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 33px;
    width: 200px;

    &:active {
      font-size: 13px;
      border: 2px solid Red;
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    &:disabled {
      border: 1px #Black;
      border-radius: 0px;
      background-color: #F9FAFB;
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <form>
      <label for="input-field">Text</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="...">
      <button>..</button>
    </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: looks related https://stackoverflow.com/a/16156683/17357155

Comment: The css looks like SCSS (mentally derived by BrettEast's comment).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So this is a few things, your css isn't valid, you've written scss syntax. If you're aware of this and the question is meant to say "scss", then you need to add `outline: none;`. Also `#black` isn't a valid colour.

Example in scss:

```css
input {
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 33px;
    width: 200px;

    &:active, &:focus { // I think you said you wanted focus as well
      font-size: 13px;
      border: 2px solid red;
      outline: none; // add this
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    &:disabled {
      border: 1px solid black; // update this
      border-radius: 0px;
      background-color: #F9FAFB;
    }
}
```

In css:

```css
input:active, input:focus { // I think you said you wanted focus as well
      font-size: 13px;
      border: 2px solid red;
      outline: none; // add this
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
```

- You can't use the `&` in regular css.
- `#Black` isn't a css colour value.
- You need `outline: none` to override the browser's default focus behaviour.

Comment: `outline: none` is the helping spot! Thank you! Using `&:active` as sub declaration can be done in SCSS style css declarations.