# I need to make input when i :focus is the icon change color

Tags: html, css, frontend

I need to make input when i :focus is the icon change color

this the code:

```
                <form action="">
                    <div>
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter input-focus-i"></i>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Twitter Username" class="input-focus-in">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change border color of textarea on :focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156594/how-to-change-border-color-of-textarea-on-focus)

Comment: .input:focus + .icon {
    color: #000;
} // this code dont work wyh

Comment: input:focus + i {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  } 

you may not need the !important

Comment: still dose not word